# Agrupar objetos sumando cierto valores que se encuentran dentro de un array con Javascript

Tags: javascript

De una API estoy recibiendo el siguiente array que muestro en la imagen. Necesito poder transformar ese array en otro array donde me agrupe los objetos que contengan el mismo `red_id` pero en los objetos agrupados necesito que se sumen los valores `actualizado` y `saldo`, y a su vez que dentro de cada objeto me genere un array el cual contenga los valores de `tr1a102_id` de cada objeto que agrupo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá les muestro un ejemplo real de 1 arreglo con 3 objetos en el cual se deben agrupar.

```javascript
[
    {
        actualizado: 5265.52
        cancelado_comprobante: null
        cancelado_fecha: null
        es_deuda: "S"
        es_transac: "S"
        estado_d: "Impago"
        fecha: "2021-01-25T00:00:00"
        imponible_ident: "Partida:0936561"
        imponible_tipo_d: "Inmueble"
        legal_d: "No Juicio"
        marca01: null
        neto_mn: null
        pagado_total_mc: 0
        reg_id: "2021-01"
        saldo: 2100
        tasa: "BAL"
        tr1a102_id: 51301885
    },
    {
        actualizado: 2332.4
        cancelado_comprobante: null
        cancelado_fecha: null
        es_deuda: "S"
        es_transac: "S"
        estado_d: "Impago"
        fecha: "2021-01-25T00:00:00"
        imponible_ident: "Partida:0936561"
        imponible_tipo_d: "Inmueble"
        legal_d: "No Juicio"
        marca01: null
        neto_mn: null
        pagado_total_mc: 0
        reg_id: "2021-01"
        saldo: 2135
        tasa: "BAL"
        tr1a102_id: 51301885
    },
    {
        actualizado: 1332.4
        cancelado_comprobante: null
        cancelado_fecha: null
        es_deuda: "S"
        es_transac: "S"
        estado_d: "Impago"
        fecha: "2021-01-25T00:00:00"
        imponible_ident: "Partida:0936561"
        imponible_tipo_d: "Inmueble"
        legal_d: "No Juicio"
        marca01: null
        neto_mn: null
        pagado_total_mc: 0
        reg_id: "2021-01"
        saldo: 135
        tasa: "BAL"
        tr1a102_id: 51301885
    }
]
```

Los únicos valores que me interesan son:

- `reg_id`
- `actualizado`
- `saldo`
- `fecha`
- `tr1a102_id` (Arreglo con esos valores)

Esto sería un ejemplo de a lo que quiero llegar por cada objeto dentro del array.

```
{
    actualizado: 2354.55,
    reg_id "2021-01",
    saldo: 3534,
    tr1a102: [51301588,51301590,51301578]        
}
```

Me estoy quemando la cabeza... ¿Alguna pista de cómo solucionarlo?

Comment: ¿Por que quieres agrupar algo que ya está diferenciado? Es decir, solo con mostrar los que tengas en X fecha, saldrán todos.

Comment: Porque necsito mostrar esa informacion en una tabla. Pero por ejemplo si hay 3 2021-01 que muestre un unico registro pero con la suma de los 3 valores de actualizado, y los tres valores de saldo

Comment: Deberías poner un ejemplo corto del array de la imágen en texto.

Comment: Ahi agregue un ejemplo de un arreglo con 3 objetos, en el cual. Segun lo que explique, deberia poder transformar ese arreglo es otro arreglo con un solo objeto (porque el reg_id de los objetos sin iguales)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para agrupar objetos a partir de una propiedad de estos, se puede usar `.reduce` con un `[[],[]]` como segundo parámetro, usando la primera posición para hacer los agrupados y el segudo para guardar los distintos, sería algo así:

```js
const obj = [{
    actualizado: 5265.52,
    cancelado_comprobante: null,
    cancelado_fecha: null,
    es_deuda: "S",
    es_transac: "S",
    estado_d: "Impago",
    fecha: "2021-01-25T00:00:00",
    imponible_ident: "Partida:0936561",
    imponible_tipo_d: "Inmueble",
    legal_d: "No Juicio",
    marca01: null,
    neto_mn: null,
    pagado_total_mc: 0,
    reg_id: "2021-01",
    saldo: 2100,
    tasa: "BAL",
    tr1a102_id: 51301885
  },
  {
    actualizado: 2332.4,
    cancelado_comprobante: null,
    cancelado_fecha: null,
    es_deuda: "S",
    es_transac: "S",
    estado_d: "Impago",
    fecha: "2021-01-25T00:00:00",
    imponible_ident: "Partida:0936561",
    imponible_tipo_d: "Inmueble",
    legal_d: "No Juicio",
    marca01: null,
    neto_mn: null,
    pagado_total_mc: 0,
    reg_id: "2021-01",
    saldo: 2135,
    tasa: "BAL",
    tr1a102_id: 51301885
  },
  {
    actualizado: 1332.4,
    cancelado_comprobante: null,
    cancelado_fecha: null,
    es_deuda: "S",
    es_transac: "S",
    estado_d: "Impago",
    fecha: "2021-01-25T00:00:00",
    imponible_ident: "Partida:0936561",
    imponible_tipo_d: "Inmueble",
    legal_d: "No Juicio",
    marca01: null,
    neto_mn: null,
    pagado_total_mc: 0,
    reg_id: "2021-01",
    saldo: 135,
    tasa: "BAL",
    tr1a102_id: 51301885
  },
  {
    actualizado: 1332.4,
    cancelado_comprobante: null,
    cancelado_fecha: null,
    es_deuda: "S",
    es_transac: "S",
    estado_d: "Impago",
    fecha: "2021-01-25T00:00:00",
    imponible_ident: "Partida:0936561",
    imponible_tipo_d: "Inmueble",
    legal_d: "No Juicio",
    marca01: null,
    neto_mn: null,
    pagado_total_mc: 0,
    reg_id: "2021-02",
    saldo: 135,
    tasa: "BAL",
    tr1a102_id: 51301885
  },
  {
    actualizado: 1332.4,
    cancelado_comprobante: null,
    cancelado_fecha: null,
    es_deuda: "S",
    es_transac: "S",
    estado_d: "Impago",
    fecha: "2021-01-25T00:00:00",
    imponible_ident: "Partida:0936561",
    imponible_tipo_d: "Inmueble",
    legal_d: "No Juicio",
    marca01: null,
    neto_mn: null,
    pagado_total_mc: 0,
    reg_id: "2021-02",
    saldo: 135,
    tasa: "BAL",
    tr1a102_id: 51301885
  }
]

const res = obj.reduce((p, c) => {

  let idx = p[1].indexOf(c.reg_id);

  if (idx === -1) {

    p[1].push(c.reg_id);

    let otmp = {
      actualizado: c.actualizado,
      reg_id: c.reg_id,
      saldo: c.saldo,
      tr1a102_id: [c.tr1a102_id]
    }

    p[0].push(otmp);
    
  } 
  else {
  
    p[0][idx].actualizado = p[0][idx].actualizado + c.actualizado;
    p[0][idx].saldo = p[0][idx].saldo + c.saldo;
    p[0][idx].tr1a102_id.push(c.tr1a102_id);
    
  }

  return p;

}, [[],[]])[0];


console.log(res)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias. Es justo lo que necesito.